# Hamcrest ArrayList matcher

Tags: java, android, mockito, hamcrest

I am trying to use a mock and check that the argument passed into the mock is the correct `ArrayList<MyModel>`. I have defined the boolean `equals` method on `MyModel`, but I can't find the right matcher that uses the `equals` method. The matchers I have been writing only compare the object_id's which are obviously different. My test looks something like so:

```java
MainActivity activity = mock(MainActivity.class);
MyRequest subject = new MyRequest(activity);
ArrrayList<MyModel> list = ...;
subject.makeRequest();
verify(activity).handleSuccess(argThat(is(list)));
```

Does anyone know a matcher that will use the boolean equal on `MyModel`?

Comment: Why this doesn't work for you? `verify(activity).handleSuccess(argThat(equalTo(expected)));`

Comment: @aim it compares the object_id's and since the argument that is called is a different instance of `ArrayList` the equality comparison returns false.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought `equalTo` invoke equal on `ArrayList` and then it applies on each element of list (like this `java.util.AbstractList#equals`)...

Comment: @aim I thought the same, but it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/funster/6143998) out (it's not android classes but it just simple idea), if you run it prints: `Equals invoked: MyModel{id=1}
Equals invoked: MyModel{id=1}`. So `equalTo` compared base on `equals` method, but not reference (or object_id's)

Comment: Post the failure message for clarity. The `equalTo` matcher indeed uses the object's built-in `equals` method. Note that `ArrayList`'s method requires the elements to be in the same order in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Hamcrest tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial#A_tour_of_common_matchers), you can use any of the following to compare using `Object.equals`:

- `argThat(is(list))`
- `argThat(is(equalTo(list))`
- `argThat(equalTo(list))`

Furthermore, [`List.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) is specifically defined to compare `e1.equals(e2)` for every element `e1` and `e2` in corresponding positions in the list.

Double-check that you've fulfilled everything you need to do to properly override `equals`:

- Does your `MyModel.equals` method receive an `Object` parameter instead of a `MyModel`? If the parameter is any type other than `Object`, it isn't a proper override and won't work.
- Is `MyModel.equals` [reflective, symmetric, transitive, and consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)? It's unlikely that your `equals` would fail in the other direction, but there's no guarantee on which object the `equals` method will be called.
- When two objects are equal, do their `hashCode` values return equal integers? Collection implementations are [free to check hash code equality as a "shortcut"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) before checking object-to-object equality.

To check those points, you may want to write a test to specifically for `equals`. I recommend [Guava's `EqualsTester`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/EqualsTester.java), which checks most of these properties automatically for you.